# Не открывается и не создается файл внутри функции-финализаторе

Tags: php, php7

```
<?php

function lastVisit()
{
    $file = fopen("visits_log.txt", "a+t") or die("File didn't create or open"); // Не создает и не открывает файл в функции.
    $date = date("d.m.Y H:i:s\r\n");                                             
    fwrite($file, $date);
    fclose($file);
}

register_shutdown_function("lastVisit");
exit();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ну так и прав на запись в каталог небось у веб сервера нет, или что?т кроме фрагмента кода, какие то данные для диагностики есть еще?

Comment: @teran Права есть, если открывать и создавать файл без финализатора, то все хорошо работает, но задача стоит именно после завершения программы записать в отдельный файл время срабатывания финализатора

Comment: используйте абсолютный путь до файла https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#92657